# Qt turkish characters case conversion

Tags: c++, qt, localization, uppercase, lowercase

We are using Qt 4.6.3 in our project. We have a Turkish character case conversion problem. For example we have a username "ismail". If we want the uppercase version of the username we got "ISMAIL" which is wrong in turkish. It should be "İSMAİL". Similary if we have "İSMAİL" and want to change case to lowercase we got "ısmaıl" which is also wrong in turkish. It should be "ismail"

We tried UTF-8, ISO-8859-9 and Windows-1254 encodings(All of them have Turkish support). But none of them worked for us.

There is good links explaning the issue. In link 2 they say the issue was solved with QByteArray but no code sample has been given.

- [1. General discussion of issue](http://www.i18nguy.com/unicode/turkish-i18n.html)
- [2. Qt related discussion of issue](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=101211)

Any help will be appreciated.

@fatih_k Below is what I do.

```
// I set this inside main.cpp
QTextCodec::setCodecForCStrings(QTextCodec::codecForName("ISO-8859-9")); 

QString userName = ui.txtUserName->text();
userName = userName.toLower();
```

Comment: can you show us your code for case conversion?

Comment: @fatih_k I updated the question with code sample

Comment: You might want to consider the ICU: International Components for Unicode. Have a look at http://site.icu-project.org/ for more information.

Comment: I have struggled with these kinds of issues in my Azeri Turkish program (http://azconvert.sourceforge.net/) and by experience I think that it's better to think for some workarounds for these issues. For example you can write your own subroutine and there first replace every `i` to `İ` and then try normal capitalization.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Qt, but may adding `QLocale::setDefault(QLocale(QLocale::Turkish, QLocale::Turkey));` before creating `userName` variable work? If it does I'll make an answer out of it.

Comment: @incrediblehulk No, it does not work. I guess QLocate is not for this kind of things

Comment: Having had similar experience myself, I would go with Mousa's approach (+1 - I have used the same approach myself).  If the text is entirely Turkish, then this approach would work.  If the text is a mix of Turkish and English, then the problem is a different one - you need to also keep track of each word and tag it as Turkish so that you can do the proper case conversion.